# PDFbox Using fallback font LiberationSans

Tags: fonts, pdfbox, pdf-conversion

When PDF is converted to Jpeg using Pdfbox, logs show warnings like:

`2022-07-20 03:16:38,743 [main] WARN PDType1Font - Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Helvetica-BoldOblique 2022-07-20 03:16:38,746 [main] WARN PDType1Font - Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Symbol 2022-07-20 03:16:38,747 [main] WARN PDType1Font - Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font ZapfDingbats`

My question is: why is it trying to process these fonts if they are not used anywhere in the document?

I converted word document with all text in Arial and then tried to convert pdf to jpeg using pdfbox.
I checked Pdf "Propertes -> Fonts" and it shows only Arial (embedded)

Comment: Please share the PDF document (link to a sharehoster) and tell what PDFBox version you're using. Do the warnings occur everytime or only the first time the document was processed?

Comment: hello, pdfBox version is 2.0.27, and pdf is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OnprFPZmUjPsdYttXLyNRsr4vytoHB7a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks; these fonts are indeed not used in that PDF. You didn't answer the second question... my suspicion is that you got the fallback messages as part of the "font cache will be re-built" activity (that has a message too), i.e. you got the message as part of that because you're running the software on a system without fonts. If you're running this on a container that doesn't have the PDFBox font cache file (.pdfbox.cache in the user directory), then you'll get it everytime you start the container.

Comment: indeed there is no .pdfbox.cache file, and these fonts are not installed. thank you for your answer. so, if i understood you correctly: all 14 of standard fonts are attempted to be saved in cache, and in case they are missing, this warning is shown?

Comment: It's a bit more complex... in 2.0 in initialization it attempts to map the standard 14 fonts to existing fonts on your system (e.g. "Helvetica" to "Arial"). The font cache doesn't cache the fonts, it just caches the information which fonts exist and what their properties are. The font cache is created at startup when it doesn't exist, or when fonts are added. Now after writing this, I think you'll get the message every time, even if the cache exists, because it tries to find what fonts to use for the standard 14 fonts. So the best would be to install them.

Comment: That all being said, the PDF does not only use Arial, it also uses the normal Helvetica: In the resources of the document page it is defined as font **F2**, and that font is set as current font multiple times in the page content stream. There even are multiple text showing operations while it is the current font, merely the strings that are shown by those instructions are empty...

Comment: @mkl true, i didn't mention helvetica to simplify my question. logs also showed warnings for helvetica, among other fonts. can you elaborate your last sentence if it's no trouble? i did not really understand what you wanted to say

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for elaboration, now it is much clearer how this works

Comment: @izidoraz *"can you elaborate your last sentence if it's no trouble?"* - in a PDF content of pages is not stored as a bitmap (except where a bitmap is explicitly included) but as a sequence of drawing instructions. And in your PDF there are drawing instructions for drawing text in Helvetica, not only for drawing text in Arial. But these instructions only draw empty strings. Thus, Acrobat's font report is only half the truth...

Comment: @mkl hm, that is useful info, thanks